# On Linux, what tools for Subversion have a tree view (like in Cervisia) for browsing branch history?

Tags: svn, tree

My company is moving from CVS to SVN. With CVS, I made branches for each production release (now svn copy) and applied limited patches to the branch for critical issues. We used Cervisia for its tree view of branch history. Is there a GUI tool on Linux that will show a similar tree for SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients has a big list of all of the Subversion clients available.

kdesvn and RapidSVN are the ones I hear most about.  If you use Eclipse you can also use one of the Eclipse plugins for Subversion which work pretty nicely as well.

Answer (score 2):

[kdesvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/) does the job, look at the [screenshots](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

tkcvs also does the tree view I want, but it is extremely slow in SVN mode (5 minutes per file)